# Update table in php

Tags: php, sql, database, pdo

**My bad.. had the name wrong.**

But it still doesn't update, it says 0 records updated. It should be 1.

This is my input field :

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['admin'] > 0)
{

echo'<div id="registreer">';
echo'<div id="titel">update</div>';
echo'<form action="done.php" method="post">';
echo'<input type="text" name="regname" placeholder="username"  /> ';
echo'<input type="password" name="regpass" placeholder="password" />';
echo'<input type="text" name="regdbhost" placeholder="host"  /> ';
echo'<input type="text" name="regdbuser" placeholder="user"  /> ';
echo'<input type="text" name="regdbpass" placeholder="dbpass"  /> ';
echo'<input type="text" name="regdbname" placeholder="dbname"  /> ';
echo'<input type="text" name="regdbtable" placeholder="table"  /> ';
echo"<button type='submit' name='regsubmit' value='register'>";
echo'<p>UPDATE</p>'; 
echo'</button>';
echo'</form>     ';   
echo'</div>';
echo'<a href="hetwerkt.php">terug</a>';
}

else if($_SESSION['admin'] < 1)
{
header("Location: hetwerkt.php");
}
?>
```

When you click on UPDATE, it will send you to done.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<?php

$servername = "----";
$username = "----";
$password = "----";
$dbname = "----";

$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['regname']); 
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['regpass']);
$regdbhost = $_POST['regdbhost'];
$regdbuser = $_POST['regdbuser'];
$regdbpass = $_POST['regdbpass'];
$regdbname = $_POST['regdbname'];
$regdbtable = $_POST['regdbtable'];

$pass = crypt($pass,'$2a$09$anexamplestringforsalt$');
try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "UPDATE info SET regdbname='$regdbname' WHERE id='".$id."'";

// Prepare statement
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

// execute the query
$stmt->execute();

// echo a message to say the UPDATE succeeded
echo $stmt->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
?>
```

And it shows this error :

```
 UPDATE info SET regdbname='test' WHERE id=''
 SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'regdbname' in 'field list'
```

What am I doing wrong? My regdbname table exist in info. Why does is say that regdbname is not found?

**My bad it was user and not info**

Comment: check it carefully your column name may have mis spellings

Comment: Post your table structure

Comment: And check if $dbname is correct.

Comment: *facepalm* it was user and not info... but when I update it says 0 records UPDATED successfully. It should be 1 instead of 0

Comment: I think your id is empty. thats why it shows 0

Comment: `echo $sql = "UPDATE info SET regdbname='$regdbname' WHERE id='".$id."'";`

Comment: **You dont have an $id defined with a valid value** and therefore as you show in your error message, the query will not update anything as it cannot find a row with the key of `empty string`

Comment: You should also be using `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` for password hashing and validation

Comment: From your comments, I think the most accurate answer to your question _What am I doing wrong?_ Is unfortunately **Everything**

Comment: Oh really? I fixed it.

Comment: So post an answer showing how you fixed it so others may benefit from it. Otherwise this question and answer set has no value for others, which is the basic ethos of SO

Comment: I had to link the id in the form.

Comment: So what about the error you actually asked about `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'regdbname'`

Comment: I edited that a long time ago lol.

Answer (score 3):

You have two issues:

1) Your table does not have column `regdbname`. Please check if column name is correct, also, if you are misspelling it.

2) `$id` is set blank. You are not setting `$id` anywhere.

Comment: Mouse over the link to see whether id is generated or not.

Comment: Does that comment mean you are running with `register_globals` set to ON? And therefore expect `$id` to automatically exist in your script??

Comment: No, it means, user clicks on the link somewhere to get to this page. He can check it in url.

Comment: @Pupil Yes of course, but he is not! And then saying well I pass the `id` on the links querystring makes me think its worth asking the question

Comment: @JustinTime **Also** If you are running this script by clicking on an anchor tag on your web page, **there will be no $_POST variables available in your script, only $_GET varriables** And only the $_GET variables that you put on the querystring using the `<a href='update.php?id=".$rw['id']."'>UPDATE</a>` So in this case ONLY `$_GET['id']`

Comment: I fixed it thanks for the help all!

Comment: @JustinTime So can you post an answer itemizing the fix, so others may benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

The updatted records is 0. this is because you didn't even define the value for **$id**.

your query is like this

```
UPDATE user SET regdbname='test' WHERE id=''
```

so it searches for a empty id, at it have none it didn't update any row and return result as 0.